# How to use for loops in a custom command?

Tags: loops, xparse

I have this nice code snippet to generate a [DI table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Tabular_integration_by_parts) for integration by parts:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{NiceArray}{cc@{\hspace*{1.0cm}}c}[create-medium-nodes, cell-space-limits=5pt]
  \toprule
     & D & I \\
  \cmidrule{2-3}
    + & x^2 & e^x \\
    - & 2x & e^x \\
    + & 2 & e^x \\
    - & 0 & e^x \\
  \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->, name suffix = -medium]
        \draw[red] (2-2) -- node [above] {} (3-3);
        \draw[red] (3-2) -- node [above] {} (4-3);
        \draw[red] (4-2) -- node [above] {} (5-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
\]
\[ \int x^2 e^x \odif{x} = x^2 e^x - 2x e^x + 2e^x + C \]
\end{document}
```

I wanted to write an `xparse` command for this code so I don't have to copy-paste it every time I do integration by parts and so that I don't have to manually modify the code when the number of rows changes. The problem is I need to use some form of a for loop to generate the rows, the alternating signs, and the arrows.

I tried to use the `lisofitems` package to have the command take a list of rows for the table and the `pgffor` package for the loops and I ended up with this code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{derivative}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DI}{ m }{
\setsepchar{;/,}
\readlist\lines{#1}
\begin{NiceArray}{cc@{\hspace*{1.0cm}}c}[create-medium-nodes, cell-space-limits=5pt]
    \toprule
        & D & I \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\lineslen}{
        \ifodd\i+\else-\fi & \lines[\i, 1] & \lines[\i, 2] \\
    }
    \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->, name suffix = -medium]
        \foreach \i in {2,...,\lineslen}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prev}{\i-1}
            \draw[red] (\prev-2) -- node [above] {} (\i-3);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
}


\begin{document}
\[ \DI{x^2,e^x ; 2x,e^x ; 2,e^x ; 0,e^x} \]
\[ \int x^2 e^x \odif{x} = x^2 e^x - 2x e^x + 2e^x + C \]
\end{document}
```

However, this code doesn't compile and produces errors, and I can't figure out what is wrong. I couldn't manage to figure out how to use for loops to generate the rows.

As you can see from the example, I'd like this command to have a syntax of:
`\DI{D1,I1 ; D2,I2 ; ...}`
where each pair is a row of the table. The alternating signs and the arrows should be taken care of automatically.

If someone could explain why my attempt failed and how to fix it, I'd highly appreciate it. A different solution that uses packages other than `listofitems` and `pgffor` is also acceptable as long as it produces the correct output.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how exactly `NiceArray` works, but usually the cells and rows of an alignment form implicit groups, so your `\foreach` loses its state at the end of the line which is what's most likely breaking it for you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works by using the L3-programming language.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{derivative}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_shaiavr_items_seq
\tl_new:N \g_shaiavr_sign_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\DI}{ m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_shaiavr_items_seq { ; } {#1}
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_shaiavr_sign_tl { + }
    \begin{NiceArray}{cc@{\hspace*{1.0cm}}c}[create-medium-nodes, cell-space-limits=5pt]
        \toprule
            & D & I \\
        \cmidrule{2-3}
        \seq_map_function:NN \l_shaiavr_items_seq \__shaiavr_line_formatter:n
        \bottomrule
    \CodeAfter
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->, name~ suffix = -medium]
          \int_step_inline:nnn {2} { \seq_count:N \l_shaiavr_items_seq }
            { \draw[red] (##1 - 2) -- (\int_eval:n { ##1 + 1 } -3); }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{NiceArray}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__shaiavr_line_formatter:n #1
  {
    \g_shaiavr_sign_tl & \clist_item:nn {#1} { 1 } & \clist_item:nn {#1} { 2 }
    \tl_if_eq:NnTF \g_shaiavr_sign_tl { + }
      { \tl_gset:Nn \g_shaiavr_sign_tl { - } }
      { \tl_gset:Nn \g_shaiavr_sign_tl { + } }
    \\
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\[ \DI{x^2,e^x ; 2x,e^x ; 2,e^x ; 0,e^x} \]
\[ \int x^2 e^x \odif{x} = x^2 e^x - 2x e^x + 2e^x + C \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @F.Pantigny off by one... :P

Comment: @F.Pantigny fixed.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for this code? I have never seen this syntax before

Comment: @ShaiAvr the syntax is described in `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`. Basically a programming interface for LaTeX3. There is also an online tutorial available (but I don't know the specific link).